# System.Data.SqlTypes or NULLABLE native types?

Tags: .net, sql-server, nullable

If you are using  a SQL Server database and you want to store null and non null values read from the database, which .NET data types are best suited, NULLABLE native types or SQLTypes?

I don't care about db portability to a different db.

Answer (score 1):

This 100% depends on what you're going to do with it. If you're interacting with `SqlCommand`s and associates, you for example have to use `DbNull`. However, my experience is that its usefulness stops there. With the rest of .NET, you're better off with native types. WPF for instance now supports `Nullable<bool>` for `CheckBox.IsChecked` which binds very well to native types, but not as nicely to the SQL types.